# Generating UML Class Diagram (UML Static Structure) from C# source code in Visio?

Tags: visio, uml, class-diagram

Say I've got some C# source code, and I want to generate a UML Class diagram from it.  In Visio I believe a UML Class diagram is called "UML Static Structure" from what I read in the Shapes accordion.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Premium and MS Visio 2007 (12.0.6536.5000) SP2 MSO (12.0.6545.5004)

How can source code be imported into Visio?

Comment: BTW, Microsoft does not consider Visio to be a software engineering tool. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/925816/76337.

Answer (score 0):

Just about every UML tool that I know of includes an import/export facility for reading in source code and generating class diagrams.  JUDE, Enterprise Architect,, Argo, Magic Draw - all of them can do it if Visio can't.

Comment: Ah, bad question wording...how I think is what I wanted to ask...(goes back to edit his question).