# What is the UML version supported in visio 2010?

Tags: uml, visio

I am trying to find out the UML version in Microsoft Visio 2010 but I cannot find any information. I did not download the 2.2 template, I only used the default UML Model Diagram under Software and Databases.

Comment: you know, I remember visio before it was acquired by microsoft, it was a really great tool. When I see microsoft saying things like this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c5a9ee4-db92-4db0-89a9-6735c304298a/visio-and-uml-20?forum=modelingandtools I feel a pain deep in my heart

Comment: That post is from eight years ago. Microsoft now supports real UML in Visual Studio Ultimate, yet continues to support DSL technology for situations where the modeling is more precise.

Comment: BTW, Microsoft does not consider Visio to be a tool for software engineering. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/925816/76337

Answer (score 1):

Visio is a very nice instrument for drawing diagrams. If I need to draw quickly a pretty diagram, I know nothing better. But it is NOT for modelling, because it doesn't support diagrams cooperation or checking.

***You can draw a correct up-to-standard UML diagram in Visio***, because you simply can draw any diagram there. But you can easily create a beautiful diagram that is NOT correct. ***It never supported any real standard***, only some inner microsoft logic.

So, if you want to impress some high manager with a beautiful picture, Visio is your choice. Now it even has some presentation possibilities, I read. But it is not so good for the work of and with programmers.

The only tool that tries to be up to the standard and sometimes maybe will be up to it, and is free, is Eclipse Papyrus. But it is raw yet. Of proprietary ones the closest to standard is EA of Sparx. Just this month I had to choose a tool and had to compare. It is really hard to go to these ugly thingies after pretty Visio, but I simply have to. Because I work with a real code and coders. If I would need to do some modelling on the high, common levels, Visio is better, because you needn't any logical strictness on this level, and all tries of precise "business modelling" are in vain yet.